# Laravel 4 - Eloquent one to many banner clicks

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I can't see where I'm going wrong with my code. I believe I have my relationships/models set up correctly but my bannerclicks table will not insert a row, and worse it seems to break the banner redirect.

MIGRATION

```
const TBL_BANNER_CLICKS = 'banner_clicks';

public function up()
    {
    // Create the clicks table
        Schema::create(self::TBL_BANNER_CLICKS, function($table){
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('banner_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('ip_address', 45);
            $table->integer('clicks')->unsigned()->default(0);
            $table->integer('created_at');

            $table->foreign('banner_id')
                ->references('id')->on('banners')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade')
            ;
        });
    }
```

MODELS

Banner.php

```
public function bannerclicks()
    {
     return $this->hasMany('BannerClick');
    }
```

BannerClick.php

```
protected $table = 'banner_clicks';

 public function banner()
{
return $this->belongsTo('Banner');
}
```

BannerController.php

```
public function redirect($id)
    {
        try {
            // Original (want to keep)
            $banner = Banner::where('id', $id)
                ->where('active', 1)
                ->firstOrFail();
            $banner->clicks++;
            $banner->save();

                    // new banner_clicks table
            $bannerclick = new BannerClick($id);
            $bannerclick->banner_id = $id;
                    $bannerclick->clicks = 1;
            $bannerclick->bannerclicks()->save($bannerclick);


            return Redirect::to($banner->url);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            return Redirect::to('/');
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<a href="{{URL::action('BannerController@redirect', $banner->id)}}" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
        <img src="{{$banner->image}}" class="img-responsive" alt="{{$banner->title}}"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be saving your relation with something like this:

```
public function redirect($id)
{
    try {
        // Original (want to keep)
        $banner = Banner::where('id', $id)
            ->where('active', 1)
            ->firstOrFail();
        $banner->clicks++;
        $banner->save();

                // new banner_clicks table
        $bannerclick = new BannerClick(array('clicks' => 1));
        $banner->bannerclicks()->save($bannerclick);


        return Redirect::to($banner->url);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

See here: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models

Or just do this:

```
        $banner = Banner::where('id', $id)
            ->where('active', 1)
            ->firstOrFail();
        $banner->clicks++;
        $banner->save();

                // new banner_clicks table
        $bannerclick = new BannerClick;
        $bannerclick->clicks = 1;
        $bannerclick->banner_id= $banner->id;
        $bannerclick->save();
```

Comment: That's something like I've been trying, been doing variations of it all day.  I tried your code but alike mine, it keeps fails and redirects to /

Comment: Try to print $ex->getMessage() instead of redirect, that should help to see what the error is. Or just put the code outside a try-catch block in the meanwhile.

Comment: It doesn't spit anything out, it just sticks at the URL which should call the controller.  http://dev.domain.com/external/7.   This is the item in my routes.php Route::get('external/{id}', array('uses' => 'BannerController@redirect'));

Comment: I suppose that's your testing domain, so I can't see it.

Comment: It's really just spitting out a default error page.  I'm working on an 'inherited' site.

Comment: I've ended up just using query builder.  Despite putting code out side the try/catch it returned no meaningful errors.  I also tried your work around but when it comes to the last 'save' line, it fails.  Seems to work with DB::table('banner_clicks')->insert(
    array('ip_address' => '127.01.01.01', 'banner_id' => 7, 'clicks' => 1)
   );